# Kendo UI Tabstrip : deselect tab using tab index in kendo tabstrip

Tags: php, kendo-ui

```
   var tabStrip = $j("#testing_tabs"+group+"").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
   tabStrip.select(0);
```

I have multiple tab and using upper code i select 0th index tab.
 same like there is any kendo tabstrip function for  deselect acivated tab
  plz help me or suggest me if possible

Answer (score 1):

Hi have a look at my answer here:

[Collapse All tabs in KendoUI TabStrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916613/collapse-all-tabs-in-kendoui-tabstrip/27917701#27917701)

Basically where you select your tab:

```
tabStrip.select(0);
```

After its selected you can get a handle on the selected tab by doing this:

```
var tab = tabStrip.select();
```

Then what I do is find the link item in that list item and trigger a click:

```
if (tab.length > 0)
{
   $(tab).find('.k-link').trigger('click');       
}
```

Another way to do this: you could check if there is an active tab via it's k-state-active class:

```
var ts = $("#tabStrip").data("kendoTabStrip");
var active = ts.tabGroup.find(".k-state-active"); 

if(active.length > 0) 
{
  ts.deactivateTab(active);
}
```